# Wordpress Site login problem with facebook, twitter and other social media

Tags: facebook, authentication, social-connect

I am running [My Wordpress Powered Website](http://ckbbd.co.nf) on a free hosted platform and the provider blocked PHP curl extension. I want to let visitors login with facebook and other social platforms. I tried with some wordpress plugins (e.g: nextend facebook connect, social connect etc.) But, those plugins requires curl extension to work. Is there any alternatives to activate facebook, twitter connect in my wordpress website for login?

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You, and those plugins, should be using the [`HTTP API`](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API) to make connections. That API will attempt to make a connection in several different ways. If your site is capable of making HTTP requests that API should be able to do it. That is largely the point of the API:

> The problem is that web hosting servers support different transports
>   and some might support none. The solution then is to support as many
>   as possible to allow for those who have hosts that disable one or two
>   to still access the web through one of the other transports that might
>   still be enabled or supported.

If the [`HTTP API`](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API) can't make a connection you will need to convince your host to alter their server configuration, or (much) more likely change hosts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick feedback. In the meantime, I found an option. This plugin [loginradius-for-wordpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/loginradius-for-wordpress/) gives me an alternative way if CURL is disabled.